# How to filter out blank messages using Kibana and ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

According to Kibana, there are many log messages where the message is "  " (2 blank spaces).

How to filter these out?

I tried matching "  ", exists and regex with \s, but those don't seem to work.

EDIT:

It seems my question was not clear. I created filters matching "  ", exists and regex, but they did not work.

Here is the JSON. There are 2 spaces between the quotes.

  `"message": "  ",`

Answer (score 0):

Trying using filter to filter out the blank messages

[image: Add a filter]

Comment: I did. What filter?

Comment: Add the field `message` and set the value to 2 blank spaces. It didnt work?

Comment: What is the mapping type of that field?

Comment: I think it is text.

Comment: `text` fields are analyzed so space characters are removed.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the analyzer is the issue. If you use the `.keyword` field, which isn't analyzed and gets created by default for text fields, you won't have that problem.

Example with the Lucene query syntax:

[image]

Example with Kibana's new query language (for this usecase they are the same):

[image]

Comment: The `.keyword` filter does not seem to do anything. Also, it does not show up on the field list (although other `.keyword` fields do). Does this feature depend on a certain version of Kibana? Or is there a config for ElasticSearch?

Comment: No, it's a thing from the mapping: If you have a text field `field` you will commonly get the analyzed content in `field` and the non-analyzed content (of the type keyword) in `field.keyword`. Check your mapping and add the field if necessary.